# Getting driver is not executable when using web driver manager?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

Using `webdrivermanager 1.7.1` to automate binary downloads for chromedriver but I'm getting "The driver is not executable" message.

I know the solution `chmod +x ../chromedriver` but required an automated process for that!!

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try that ->  chmod 777 *

Comment: @ShubhamJain you mean manually or making completes files in dir??

Comment: complete file in dir

Comment: Which operative system (Linux, Mac) and architecture (32, 64 bits) are you using?

Comment: using linux 64bit (centos 7)

Comment: That's weird because webdrivermanager sets the executable flag once the binary (chromedriver in this case) is extracted. I have tried this in Ubuntu 64 (which it should be the same than Centos) and for me is working fine. Could you try removing your chromedriver cache (~/.m2/repository/webdriver/chromedriver/linux64) and try again? Just to find out whether it is a consistent problem or not.

Comment: FYI: been tried with v1.6.2, 1.7.0 and 1.7.1 with chrome driver 2.29 version. still getting the same error (-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep  6 10:56 chromedriver)

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue here as well. Chrome was working but not Firefox. Removed geckodriver folder and tried as well.

But I did chmod 777 on geckdriver and it worked.

```
package frameWork;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class BaseClass {

    public WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("src/main/java/frameWork/data.properties");

        p.load(f);
        String browser = p.getProperty("browser");

        if(browser.equals("chrome")) {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

        } else if(browser.equals("firefox")) {
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        } else {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver","/usr/bin/safaridriver");
            driver = new SafariDriver();
        }

        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }

}
```

Error

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.8.0 [TestNG] Running:
>   /private/var/folders/q1/2vf46m2546926xbq00dw66l40000gp/T/testng-eclipse-1456133345/testng-customsuite.xml
>
> [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Latest version
>   of [wires, geckodriver] is 0.20.0 Mar 13, 2018 10:49:44 AM
>   org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
>   WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: logged_in=no;
>   domain=.github.com; path=/; expires=Sat, 13 Mar 2038 05:19:44 -0000;
>   secure; HttpOnly". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Sat, 13 Mar 2038
>   05:19:44 -0000 WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has
>   occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by
>   org.rauschig.jarchivelib.FileModeMapper$FileSystemPreferencesReflectionChmodCommand
>   (file:/Users/basil/.m2/repository/org/rauschig/jarchivelib/0.7.1/jarchivelib-0.7.1.jar)
>   to method
>   java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.chmod(java.lang.String,int)
>   WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of
>   org.rauschig.jarchivelib.FileModeMapper$FileSystemPreferencesReflectionChmodCommand
>   WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further
>   illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access
>   operations will be denied in a future release Mar 13, 2018 10:49:50 AM
>   org.rauschig.jarchivelib.FileModeMapper$UnixPermissionMapper chmod
>   WARNING: Could not set file permissions of
>   /Users/basil/.m2/repository/webdriver/geckodriver/macos/0.20.0/geckodriver.
>   Exception was: null [main] WARN io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader -
>   Error setting file
>   /Users/basil/.m2/repository/webdriver/geckodriver/macos/0.20.0/geckodriver-v0.20.0-macos.tar.gz
>   as executable [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager -
>   Exporting webdriver.gecko.driver as
>   /Users/basil/.m2/repository/webdriver/geckodriver/macos/0.20.0/geckodriver-v0.20.0-macos.tar.gz
>   FAILED: basePageNavigation java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver
>   executable does not exist:
>   /Users/basil/.m2/repository/webdriver/geckodriver/macos/0.20.0/geckodriver-v0.20.0-macos.tar.gz
>     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:141)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
>     at frameWork.BaseClass.initializeDriver(BaseClass.java:32)  at
>   frameWork.HomePage.basePageNavigation(HomePage.java:11)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Comment: java version "9.0.4" & Maven 3.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Try with this WebDriverManager version:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
```